# How can I ROLLBACK my database to a specific date?

Tags: oracle

How can I ROLLBACK my database to specific date or point without create a ROLLBACK point?

Comment: Or with flashback, if it's configured and you have the date you need still in the flashback window. Do you really mean the whole database, or your schema, or specific tables?

Comment: a rollback is usually used for volatile sessions, do you have any backup?

Comment: Do you need to "rollback" the entire database or can you rollback specific tables?

Comment: Meant to link to [the flashback database documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/backup.1111/e10642/rcmflash.htm); but caveats above still apply!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Flashback technology you can do it OR using old backup,
Else you couldn't rollback.